# Jquery background slide

Tags: jquery, css, background

I want to make a UL based menu with css html and Jquery. I want to put a :hover in every

```
<li><a href="#"></li>
```

to change the link's background. But what i want to do is: slide the  background from left to the right when :hover. In fact, I want to animate a background position change with Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actually** i realized that my prior suggestion was not exactly what you want .. as it does more than what you want..

http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/ This plugin adds feature to animate background position.

---

This should get you going:

Actual page:
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/animate-navigation-with-css-jquery/

Demo:
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/fancy-navigation/

A lot of other good stuff in there as well.